# Dependency Problems installing Google Chrome package due to xdg-utils error

Tags: installation, google-chrome, dependencies

Trying to install Google Chrome on my fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install. I have run a full apt-get upgrade and apt-get update on this system before installing Chrome. I downloaded the 32-bit deb package from www.chrome.com and opened it in Ubuntu Software Center. It gets almost to the end and then throws up the following error.

Any insight?

```
Unpacking google-chrome-stable:i386 (from .../google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:i386:
 google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2).
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install xdg-utils` ? Then running the installer again?

Comment: I would change to `chromium-browser` since google has dropped support for 32bit chrome builds.

Answer (score 4):

I followed the instructions from [**here**](http://web.archive.org/web/20131020051158/http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/install-google-chrome-using-apt-get-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) and finished with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have no idea how or why, as I'm completely new to Linux, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure your OS is 32 bit. Your message looks like the one I got when I tried to download the 32 bit version on my 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to install the google-chrome-stable-i386 via the software update. However; I was able to install in with the following line of code via the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

so far it is working with out issue..

Oh, I have Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS